# c# class object filtering

Tags: c#, winforms

I have sucha a situation. I have list inside which I am holding objects of one class (this objects has 6 properties "Name", "Type", "Index", "Value", "Status", "Parameter"). Later I am binding it with gridView. 
Now I would like to be able to make a filter for each of this properties. I want to be able for example to insert into textbox "Name" : John, and I would like gridView to display only rows where I have John.

Second thing is that I would like to be able to mix filters, so have for example "Name" set to : 'John' and "Index" to : 5, and display "John" with "Index" : 5.

How can I do this?

Now I only have function to insert everything into list. This objects are stored inside Middle property of class WholeLine.

```
Correction method = new Correction();

while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
string[] _columns = line.Split(",".ToCharArray());
object returnValue;

MyColumns mc = new MyColumns();
mc.Time = _columns[0];
mc.Information = _columns[1];
mc.Description = _columns[2];

if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(mc.Information) )
{ continue; }
else
{
     returnValue = method.HandleRegex(mc.Information);
}
Line main = new Line();
main.LeftColumn = mc.Time;
main.Middle= returnValue;
main.RightColumn = mc.Description;
list3.Add(main);
}
```

EDIT:

It is not that simple in my situation (I think...), because I have main class where I have this while shown above. Later I call method HadleRegex from class `Correction` . Bellow I will show how it looks like:

```
class Correction
{
    private MoreInfor _MoreInfor = new MoreInfor();

    public MoreInfor MoreInfor { get { return _ID; } }

Correction sk = new Correction();

            Match matches = Regex.Match(newStr, @"\b(?:complete\b)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            if (matches.Success)
            {

                string[] lines = newStr.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                Regex regex1 = new Regex(@"^(?:(?<C0>Command) (?:answer|sent) from (?<C1>\S+) to (?<C2>\S+) (?<C3>.+))$");
                var matches1 = lines.Select(line => regex1.Match(line));

                foreach (var match in matches1)
                {
                    sk._MoreInfor.Name= match.Groups["C1"].ToString();
                    sk._MoreInfor.Type = match.Groups["C2"].ToString();
                    sk._MoreInfor.Value = match.Groups["C3"].ToString();
                    sk._MoreInfor.Index = match.Groups["C4"].ToString();
                }
            }
   return sk;
}

public class MoreInfo
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Index { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Parameter { get; set; }
}
```

This returned vale of class `Correction` is later passed to `returnValue` from my main class and added to `Middle` property of class `Line`

I'm sorry if I really messed up!

Answer (score 2):

You can use linq - [where](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)

```
var result = list.Where(x => x.Name == textBoxName.Text).ToList();
```

This assumes your textbox will search for a name

For multiple filters,

```
list.Where(x => x.Property == "something" && x.Name == textBoxName.Text).ToList();
list.Where(x => result.Where(ix => x.Property == "something").ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

use linq to filer

```
yourlist.Select(x=>x.Name == "John");
```

Answer (score 0):

You may define some "NoFilter" values. For instance index may be -1, or Name = ""

```
public List<person> FilterPersons (List<person> persons,
                    string name = "",
                    string type = "",
                    int index = -1,
                    int value = -1,
                    int status = -1,
                    string parameter = "")
{
    return persons
           .Where
           (
               x=>
               (name == "" || x.Name == name)
               && (type == "" || x.Type == type)
               && (index == -1 || x.Index == index)
               && (value == -1 || x.Value == value)
               && (status == -1 || x.Status == status)
               && (parameter == "" || x.Parameter == parameter)
           )
           .Select(x=>x);
}
```

And then you may call it as:

```
filterPersons = FilterPersons(persons: persons,name: "John");
```

or

```
filterPersons = FilterPersons(persons: persons,index: 10, status: 5);
```